# JMeter change variable value not working

Tags: jmeter, load-testing, beanshell

i'm using jmeter beanshell preprocessor like this.. i'm trying to get body data values, and do some logics before sending it.. here's what i tried

```
import org.apache.commons.codec.digest.DigestUtils;
import org.apache.jmeter.config.Argument;
import org.apache.jmeter.config.Arguments;
import com.eclipsesource.json.JsonObject;


String toMD5 = "test";
String result = DigestUtils.md5Hex(toMD5); 
vars.put("signatureCreate", result);
vars.put("dummy", "dummyText");
vars.put("dummy2", "initial");
vars.put("dummy2", "initialS");

Arguments arguments = sampler.getArguments();
log.info(arguments.getArgumentCount().toString());
    Argument argument = arguments.getArgument(0);
    String name = argument.getName();
    String value = argument.getValue(); 

JsonObject requestStr = JsonObject.readFrom(value);
String testLog = requestStr.get("storeName").asString();
vars.put("dummy2", testLog);
log.info(testLog);
log.info("dnsjdnsjndsd");
```

the strange thing is, i declared "dummy2" with value "initialS", and re-change the value of it in the bottom of my code (see code above).. but the value doesn't changed..

i tried to print out log at very bottom of the code (just to make sure the code executed fully) and the log showed.. but the value of "dummy2" was not changed..  what's wrong with this code?

Comment: try to print testLog before, what you get?

Comment: @user7294900 i've already print out the testLog (kindly see my code above), in the log, the testLog value is correct, i mean the same value as the value in the body data

Answer (score 0):

1. Always look into *jmeter.log* file, normally it should have enough information in order to get to the bottom of the issue
2. Be aware that starting from JMeter 3.1 [it is recommended to use Groovy for any form of scripting](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting), [Groovy has much better performance than Beanshell](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black) does, moreover it comes with [built-in JSON support](http://groovy-lang.org/json.html).

With regards to your script itself my expectation is that you simply don't have [minimal-json](https://github.com/ralfstx/minimal-json) jar in [JMeter classpath](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#classpath).